# how to set ledger into geth without private key?

Tags: go-ethereum, ledger-nano-s

i have a problem with geth.
is it possible to import a ledger to geth.
i want to use ledger nano as cold storage.
but i didn't see any option for this.
only option that already exists is importing private key to geth.
so this is completely opposite of cold wallet concept